# Combining two columns from different files by common strings

Tags: unix, awk, sed, echo

I have two tab-delimited files.

**file-1**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | K02377 |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 |  |
| NODE_2_length_39753_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | K02377 |
| NODE_2_length_49771_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 | K16554 |

................................
.....................**totally 391443 lines**

**file2**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | 56.54 |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 | 51.0 |
| NODE_2_length_39753_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | 12.6 |
| NODE_2_length_49771_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 | 18.9 |

................................
.....................**totally 391249 lines**

I want to merge this two files keeping the first column the same.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | K02377 | 56.54 |
| NODE_1_length_59711_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 |  | 51.0 |
| NODE_2_length_39753_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_1 | K02377 | 12.6 |
| NODE_2_length_49771_cov_84.026979_g0_i0_2 | K16554 | 18.9 |

The problem is as the first file have almost 190 more lines I cannot directly combine them as it will give wrong output. Is there any way I can combine these files by the common string from the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1]=$2;next } { map1[$1]=$2 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for (i in map) { print i"\t"map[i]"\t"map1[i] } }' file-1 file2
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { 
               map[$1]=$2;                                  # Process the first file only and set up an array called map with the first space separated field as the index and the second the value
               next 
             } 
             { 
               map1[$1]=$2                                  # When processing the second file, set up an second array called map1 and use the first field as the index and the second the value.
             } 
         END { 
               PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";         # Set the index ordering
               for (i in map) { 
                 print i"\t"map[i]"\t"map1[i]                # Loop through the map array and print the values along with the values in map1.
               } 
              }' file-1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked smoothly. Thanks for explanation too.

Comment: Hi, what if My initial file-2 has 3 columns (the output file of the above command). I want to merge it with another file (file-4) with two columns (the first column of both the files is the same). The final output should have 1-common column followed by matched rows of 2nd and 3rd column of file-2 and matched rows of 2nd column of file-4.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU join):

```
join -t$'\t' file1 file2
```

N.B. Some shells may not accept `$'\t'` in which case use a literal tab, this can be entered via the teminal cntrl-v tab key sequence.

Comment: It works only for the lines having a string in both columns. as there are some blank rows in my file it, the output of this command does not consider blanks.

Comment: @Shail every line in file1 and file2 should contain a tab. If not the file needs to be fixed before the join. Use `sed -i '/\t/!s/$/\t/' file1 file2` then the solution above.